# WPF app won't run UI/MainWindow (Update: starting after 6+ min of waiting!)

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a new WPF application in Visual Studio (Community 2015) to do some really simple testing. However, the application won't start.

I've literally not changed anything, it's the original empty project, just with the MainWindow.xaml, App.xaml etc (Checked startup URI:)

```
<Application x:Class="Sandbox2.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sandbox2"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

and App.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;

namespace Sandbox2
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
    }
}
```

Main Window.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Sandbox2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sandbox2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindows.cs:

using System.Windows;

```
namespace Sandbox2
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Task manager shows the .exe has started, but it's using almost no memory:
[image]

No windows open, the only way of closing it is through task manager. Breakpoints in window constructor on "InitializeComponent" are never hit.

I'm stumped, I'd think I've got the project configured wrong, but it's just all the defaults. I couldn't find anything similar on Stackoverflow or google... anyone have any idea why this is happening?

**EDIT:** I dug into the generated code for App.xaml.cs, down to app.g.i.cs. A breakpoint in "Main" is never hit!

```
#pragma checksum "..\..\App.xaml" "{406ea660-64cf-4c82-b6f0-42d48172a799}" "2BDF5940107DE9786768C3CB1E5EB012"
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using Sandbox2;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Automation;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Media.Effects;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;
using System.Windows.Media.TextFormatting;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Shell;


namespace Sandbox2 {


    /// <summary>
    /// App
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : System.Windows.Application {

        /// <summary>
        /// InitializeComponent
        /// </summary>
        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
        public void InitializeComponent() {

            #line 5 "..\..\App.xaml"
            this.StartupUri = new System.Uri("MainWindow.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);

            #line default
            #line hidden
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Application Entry Point.
        /// </summary>
        [System.STAThreadAttribute()]
        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
        public static void Main() {
            Sandbox2.App app = new Sandbox2.App();
            app.InitializeComponent();
            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 2** Yeah, officially really werid. It works. I just let it sit for 10 min, and the main thread did kick off. After 6 minuites 38 seconds of... nothing. (Again, this time 8:24!)

You can see here, the memory spikes from it's idle of a few hundred kb, to a sensible amount. The Main method breakpoint was hit, and when I continue the program starts up with my empty window!

What on earth could cause that?

[image]

Comment: Could you please add code in App.xaml.cs?

Comment: is anything doing new MainWindow() anywhere?  otherwise, use a debugger and step in?

Comment: @pol, added code for App.xaml.cs (and app.g.i.cs)

Comment: @JohnGardner I dove into the generated code and it's main method, and a breakpoint there isn't hit. I'm unsure where earlier/else I can put a breakpoint!

Comment: make sure you've set the startup object properly in the [project properties](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/479467/Startup_object.jpg).

Comment: @HighCore, it was "(Not Set)", changed to "Sandbox2.App" but does the same thing.

Strangely... It just managed to start (hit main breakpoint). I was working on something else though, it definitely took longer than 5 or 10 minutes. I've tried restarting it and it's still not doing anything. It might be that it's just taking in the order of 10+ min to start up!

Comment: in your diagnostic hub screenshot, the events group look like it has a solid gray line of an infinite number of events, instead of being blank.  there wasn't tons of output or anything?  nothing shows up in the events list but your breakpoint, so that's odd.  398,292 ms is a long time to wait for an app to start!

Comment: Try to disable any running antivirus and try again, though it is supposed not to be a problem as you have created the application, it was not downloaded from the Internet.

Comment: Well, logged into the computer this morning and it's fine, all fixed! Maybe it was something to do with the anti-virus.

Answer (score -1):

For any future person who stumbles upon this with the same issue. It's all fixed now. I'm sorry though, I've no idea why. I gave up last night, logged into the computer this morning and the startup time is back to a second or two.

The only advice I can think of is to restart the computer...

It could be some quirk of the antivirus as Abdulkarim Kanaan suggests above.

Comment: Gaming software that release memory, antivirus that kills all my VS debugging, etc.